# Retrieve email address from imap header

Tags: php, regex, header, preg-match, imap

I'm using php imap function `imap_header` to extract full header and `imap_fetch_overview` to extract raw header. Both the functions gives me stdClass object and arrays respectively.

I would like to always clean my from and to before further processing. Sometimes a FROM or TO can contain some thing like this,
`Test user <test@test.com>`

Also currently in my FROM I only see `Test User` and no email address until I use firebug.

How do I just get the test@test.com from these objects, arrays?

This is the result I get from `imap_fetch_overview`

```
   Array
   (
     [0] => stdClass Object
     (
        [subject] => Testing
        [from] => Test User 
        [to] => testuser2@test.com
        [date] => Wed, 17 Apr 2013 18:43:46 +0530
        [message_id] => <abcdef1244.93784jgsfk@test.com>
        [size] => 3443
        [uid] => 1234
        [msgno] => 123
        [recent] => 0
        [flagged] => 0
        [answered] => 0
        [deleted] => 0
        [seen] => 0
        [draft] => 0
        [udate] => 1366204439
    )

)
```

There is a hidden `<test@test.com>` next to Test User. How do I extract that email address?

Similarly this is what I get from `imap_header`

```
  stdClass Object
  (
     [date] => Wed, 17 Apr 2013 18:43:46 +0530
     [Date] => Wed, 17 Apr 2013 18:43:46 +0530
     [subject] => Test
     [Subject] => Test
     [message_id] => <abcdef1244.93784jgsfk@test.com>
     [toaddress] => testuser@test.com
     [to] => Array
     (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [mailbox] => testuser
                [host] => test.com
            )

    )

    [fromaddress] => Test User 
    [from] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [personal] => Test User
                [mailbox] => test
                [host] => test.com
            )

    )

    [reply_toaddress] => Test User 
    [reply_to] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [personal] => Test User
                [mailbox] => test
                [host] => test.com
            )

    )

    [senderaddress] => Test User
    [sender] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [personal] => Test User
                [mailbox] => test
                [host] => test.com
            )

    )

    [Recent] =>  
    [Unseen] => U
    [Flagged] =>  
    [Answered] =>  
    [Deleted] =>  
    [Draft] =>  
    [Msgno] =>  123
    [MailDate] => 17-Apr-2013 13:13:59 +0000
    [Size] => 3443
    [udate] => 1366204439
)
```

A `preg_match` would be the obvious answer but just cant seem to figure out how to perform it on from bit where email address is not seen in the browser but is present when inspected with firebug. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can go one step further with [`imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist):

```
$toAddresses = imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist('Test user <test@test.com>', 'localhost');

print_r($toAddresses);

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [mailbox] => test
            [host] => test.com
            [personal] => Test user
        )

)
```

Comment: The problem is I don't see my email address in FROM at all until I use firebug. It's there in form of `<test@test.com></test@test.com>` tags. Hence `imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist() doesn't work too. I already have that array form (mailbox, host,personal) from my full header, but how do I get the email addr that is otherwise not seen in the browser

Comment: use view-source, not firebug. fire-bug and your browser treat it as HTML tags (because it starts with `<`). alternatively deliver the output as `Content-Type: text/plain`, but I guess for your debugging you just want to view source.

Answer (score 0):

If name of array of std object is $arr

```
$arr[0]->to
```

returns what you want.

in second case

$stdObject <- object that is returned by second function

```
foreach($stdObject->to as $to)
{
 echo $to->mailbox;
 echo $to->host;
}
```

Comment: In the first case `$arr[0]->to` gives me Test User. Doesn't give me the email address. However after inspecting it thru firebug, I can see that it treats my email address as tags. `<test@test.com></test@test.com>`. Any ideas why it's doing that and what should be done to rectify it?

Answer (score 0):

I've just discovered this thread and whilst it's old I hope this comment might help. I *believe* I've answered the query. As it happens, the format of the sender email is what's causing the issue.

`From Name <from@name.com>`

Because of the <> tag, the browser is making it into an HTML tag, I guess something akin to a span. By using str_replace to change "<" into " " (or whatever) you remove the issue before it gets to HTML